# Verify C# HMACSHA256 in PHP

Tags: c#, php, wordpress, umbraco, sha256

I have a user's data and the passwords are hashed with HMAC-SHA256 and encrypted with AES (Umbraco CMS with uCommerce). I need to import that password so the old user could log in to the new website (using WordPress and WooCommerce). I have a secret key (salt) from the previous website and I intend to make the old password 'readable' and verified in WordPress as the password would re-hashed again using WordPress hashing algorithm when the user login.

I read the **hash_hmac** function in PHP and does it can be applied in WordPress authentication alongside WordPress's own hashing algorithm (MD5)?

Thank you.

---

*Update*

Previous title: HMAC-SHA256 hashed password in WordPress from another CMS

I have a website using **Umbraco CMS (written in C#)** and **want to replicate their hashing algorithm** in **WordPress (PHP)** to migrate the old password hashed in the previous website. I try to replicate the hash that I get from the DB:

- Password: `likeasmyname`
- Hashed: `X9gbVOGeHJPbifmaVCCYcg==qXwkrnY3HxAPB0bjnBxw3IAe3n0yX5q7Dk/I+MTAiX4=`

That is the generated hash from the password "likeasmyname" using HMACSHA256 with salt in 128bit length. Based on their algorithm, they hash the password and prepend the salt before stored the DB. Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v8/8.5.5/src/Umbraco.Core/Security/MembershipProviderBase.cs)

I infer that the `X9gbVOGeHJPbifmaVCCYcg==` is the salt and the rest is the password `qXwkrnY3HxAPB0bjnBxw3IAe3n0yX5q7Dk/I+MTAiX4=`

I try this:

```
<?
$password= "likeasmyname";
$passwordUtf16 = mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF-16LE');

$hashFull = "X9gbVOGeHJPbifmaVCCYcg==qXwkrnY3HxAPB0bjnBxw3IAe3n0yX5q7Dk/I+MTAiX4="; 
$hashSalt = "X9gbVOGeHJPbifmaVCCYcg=="; 
$hashPassword = "qXwkrnY3HxAPB0bjnBxw3IAe3n0yX5q7Dk/I+MTAiX4=";

$hashSaltDecoded = base64_decode($hashSalt);
$hashAlgo = hash_hmac('sha256', $hashSaltDecoded . $passwordUtf16, $hashSaltDecoded, true);
echo $hashAlgo;
?>
```

Result:

```
Result: lg2AaF0ogBpop02CgdmeM3efENQwagXWpFhW7zG0Jpk=
Expected: qXwkrnY3HxAPB0bjnBxw3IAe3n0yX5q7Dk/I+MTAiX4=
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Usually, the source code for such systems is readable for everyone, such that you can reverse-engineer these algorithms. But if you want to avoid too close dependencies (what if your CMS changes mechanisms to store the passwords?), you should look up proper SSO / OAuth techniques

Comment: I am not sure if I get the question right. If it is hashed you are not going to be able to get back the password and make it 'readable'. Hash algorithm is only one way, that's why they are used instead of storing the password in clear text. If the other system uses the same hashing then maybe you can use the same hashed password, but that is a long shot.

Comment: @NicoHaase We are sort of short-budgeted and couldn't implement the SSO at the moment. Although it is a good idea!

Comment: @Crick3t We want WordPress could detect the Umbraco's hash so the old user can log in with their old password and re-hash them according to WordPress hash algorithm. I'll update my process using standard PHP.